# Window.Open with Search

Tags: javascript

I have the following window open method:

```
                    <script>
                    function searchForm(form){
                        window.open("test.php?Search=", "newwindow", "scrollbars=yes", "width=800", "height=600", + form.s.value)
                        return false;
                    }
                </script>

                <form method="get" onsubmit="return searchForm(this)" class="form-inline" role="form" />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control input-sm" name="s" type="text" onFocus="if (this.value == 'Search Events') {this.value='';" />
                    </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-text">Lookup Existing Data</button>            
                </form>
```

I want the new window to open using the parameters above, but when I add them, it breaks the data in the Search, if I remove the parameter values, it works but the window opens in a new tab.

Comment: What if you remove the `+` in `+ form.s.value`?

Comment: What if you add `form.s.value` to the ***first argument*** (behind `Search=`) instead of randomly at the very end of `open()`?

Comment: Hi putvande, I tried that but it still does not work, it just opens the new window using the parameters, but stripping the search criteria.

Comment: Thank you deceze, that fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to append your data to the URL! You are shoving the code to append the string as an argument of its own instead of as part of the statement that constructs the URL.

Additionally, the window description parameters need to be passed as a *single* argument.

Finally, you need to escape user input when putting it into a data format (like a URL).

```
window.open(
  "test.php?Search=" + encodeURIComponent(form.s.value),
  "newwindow",
  "scrollbars=yes,width=800,height=600"
);
```